# Doing a 'git pull' with Apache from a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, git, apache, git-pull

I have a Git repository on Bitbucket named "foo-apps". I have a Linux web server with a local clone of this repository, and I want this server's associated Apache web page to do some Git commands with this repository, such as `git pull` and `git checkout`, via a Bash script. The problem is, only the user "foo" has permission to associate with the "foo-apps" repository, and the web page runs as the Apache user, "www-data".

It seems that www-data can do `git log` and some other commands on the local repository, but not the `git pull` or the `git checkout` command. (Just so you know my system: I have an HTML file that contains JavaScript, which contains an AJAX request, which calls a PHP file, which calls my Bash script, which has the Git commands in it.)

What are some ways that I can successfully get those Git commands to work when the process is triggered by the web interface? I am not opposed to any working suggestions, even if they include a complete overhaul of my system... however, I would like to have the simplest effective solution with what I've already got.

Here are some ideas I've thought of and tried out a bit. None of them seem to work, but keep in mind that I've only "half tried" them as I didn't have confidence I was using preferred methods:

- Giving www-data permission on my Bitbucket repository
- Giving Apache access to foo's ssh keys
- Somehow switching to user foo in the script, like with `sudo`, `su`, etc.. (I think this type of thinking is more along the lines of what I want... I don't have a lot of control over the settings of the Bitbucket repository. I am fine putting a password in a script, too.)

This web server is on a closed network, and security is not a very high concern for me.

I don't know if it's useful, but here are some of the main Git related errors I've received when trying these methods:

`error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied`

`fatal: BUG: get_tempfile_fd() called for inactive object`

`/usr/bin/git: /usr/bin/git: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: Create a shell script that can do the operations you want in the directories you want to do them, and then give Apache passwordless sudo access to run that script (and nothing else) as `foo`.

Comment: That seems like the simplest thing to do. I didn't realize that you could give a specific user permission to run a specific file in /etc/sudoers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1184619) page (thanks [odyniec](http://odyniec.net/)).

I had to add this line to the /etc/sudoers file:

`www-data ALL=(foo) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/my_bash_script.sh`

This let Apache have the permission to run that specific script I wanted. And then from my PHP file, instead of running

`shell_exec("/var/www/html/my_bash_script.sh");`

I had to run

`shell_exec("sudo -u foo /var/www/html/my_bash_script.sh");`

This answer seems secure and simple.